# Not able to align specific patterns side by side in this grid

Tags: python, function

[image]

So  I tried different methods to do this like:

```
a = ("+ " + "- "*4)
b = ("|\n"*4)
print(a + a + "\n" + b + a + a + "\n" + b + a + a)
```

But the basic problem  I am facing is how to print the vertical pattern on the sixth column i.e in the middle as well as, at the last

Answer (score 0):

I got it actually and thought of posting the solution I might help others:
we ought to make use of the do_twice and do_four function:

```
def draw_grid_art():
  a = "+ - - - - + - - - - +"
  def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

  def do_four(f):
      do_twice(f)
      do_twice(f)
  def vertical():
      b = "|         |         |"
      print(b)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)
  do_four(vertical)
  print(a)
```

I was able to come up with only this.As always anyone is free to shorten/organize my code as I think it is long